# Using GCC to output commented & annotated intermediate files

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

Is it possible to convince GCC to emit an intermediate file which shows:

1. comments
2. original source
3. expanded macro definitions
4. optimizations applied by compiler
5. resulting C or C++ code which will be turned in to assembly code?

I'd rather see intermediate C/C++ instead of assembler, but I can use just assembler too if it's sufficiently annotated.

I am trying to reverse engineer a library composed almost entirely of macros in order to extend it.  I'd also like to see the effects of optimization, in order to give the compiler more opportunities to do more optimization.  (In other words, to see where my previous attempts have been ineffective)

Comment: Which options are you already aware of? I suppose you know `-E` for preprocessing (and therefore expanding macros) and `-S -g -fverbose-asm` for some kind of semi-annotated assembly. I'm not sure whether GCC can emit intermediate-language code after optimization, you might want to have a look at Clang for that - it compiles to LLVM intermediate language which is fully specified and possibly easier to read than x86 asm. (I don't think any compiler actually does their optimizations on the C(++) source and would therefore emit readable C(++) optimized code.)

Comment: @us2012: I am (parially) aware of `-save-temps`, but for reasons that are eluding me, I can't get it to work.  As in, I can't find the resulting files.

Answer (score 7):

GCC applies optimizations not in the C++-code directly but in some internal language-independant format (called GIMPLE) which cannot be reverted into C++ code that easily.

Depending on what you want, you can either

- just expand macros: `g++ -E`
- or look at an assembler output where you can see which line of C++ code maps to which assembler block:

  ```
  g++ -g ... && objdump -S output
  ```

  I don't recommend outputting assembler directly from gcc (with -S) as the generated annotations are almost useless.

Answer (score 5):

1 and 2 are shown in, well, the original source.

3 You can get source with expanded macro definitions (in fact fully preprocessed) with `-E`.

4 The intermediate code at various stage of optimization can be obtained with `-da` or various `-fdump-rtl-xxx`, `-fdump-tree-xxx` and other `-fdump-xxx` options.

These are documented here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options

5 I don't think GCC does source-to-source transformations, so the resulting C++ code is the original C++ code.

What transformations GCC does is described here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Passes.html#Passes